# c++17 namespaces, is it possible to force qualified access ALWAYS?

Tags: c++, namespaces

to my surprise, when a function is declared in the same namespace as a variable, the function may access that variable without qualification.

```
// file qqq.cpp

namespace aaa {
    void f();
    int x; 
}

void aaa::f() {
    aaa::x;       // 0. INTENDED ACCESS to x in namespace aaa (also works)
    x;            // 1. SURPRISE: x can be accessed without aaa:: qualification
    bool x;       // 2. SURPRISE: given (1) why is it allowed to redefine x?
}
```

question:

A) is there any way to ensure that all objects in a namespace be blind to its fellow constituents, and to require access always through :: ?

B) if not, what would be the correct coding practice to obtain the desired behavior?

C) if not, an alternative solution would be to separate the each namespace into 2, one for functions and another for variables, like f_aaa and v_aaa. but this seems quite clunky and ugly in practical use, eg. void f_sqlite::myfun() { v_sqlite::myvar; } instead of just void sqlite::myfun() { sqlite::myvar; }

---

edit 1: context, the "problem" im trying to solve:

refactoring several thousand lines of code, namespaces was thought to be suitable for bundling related elements, eg. an "sqlite" namespace for sqlite utility functions and variables used throughout the code base. forced access through :: would be an excellent way of increasing clarity and avoiding name clashes and hiding. separate namespaces for "one bundle" would defeat the purpose. classes would not seem conceptually appropriate.

edit 2:

D) is it possible to get a WARNING (enable compiler flag) to signal when a function in namespace aaa accesses a variable in namespace aaa without qualification?

edit 3:

i think i will end up using "separate namespaces" anyway, but by way of nested namespaces

```
// file qqq.cpp

namespace aaa::f { // namespace for functions
    void f();
    void g();
}

namespace aaa::v { // namespace for variables
    int x;
}

// definition of function f inside namespace aaa::f

void aaa::f::f() {
    aaa::v::x;    // only way of accessing x in aaa::v (good) (ugly)
    x;            // compiler error (good)
    bool x;       // normal scope hiding (good)
    g();          // works: ARGH! would like to force qualifying with aaa::f::
}
```

still rather ugly though. and! functions can still call each other unqualified, objects can still call/reference each other unaqulified. would really have been nice to simply be able to put some "force-qualifier" (like "private") on all or some element inside a namespace.

Comment: Why is it a surprise that a function in the scope of `aaa` can access other symbols in the same scope? That's simply part of the rules of C++.

Comment: As for the second "surprise", it's also part of scoping. You can define symbols in any scope, even if they *hide* symbols in a parent scope.

Comment: Note this is the same even in c++98.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ok, thanks, accepted. can you tell me how to package functions and variables in a way that access to the packages elements must alway be through "a certain name". creating an object containing all elements seems clumsy, since i would like to access this package in different functions/files, but only a few elements in/from any one function/file.

Comment: Separate classes or namespaces is the only way to do what you seem to want. But, what is the *real* problem you need to solve? What is the purpose of the solution you seek? Right now this is all really an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. refactoring several thousands of code, namespaces was thought to be suitable for bundling related elements, fx an "sqlite" namespace for sqlite utility functions used throughout the code base. forced access through <namespace>::  would be an excellent way of increasing clarity and avoiding name clashes and hiding. separate namespaces would defeat the purpose. classes would not seem conceptually appropriate.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, is it possible to get a WARNING (enable compiler flag) to signal when a function in namespace aaa accesses a variable in namespace aaa without qualification?

Comment: @ㄈㄟㄈㄟ It might be possible to modify the rules of a static analyzer program to issue a warning about this, but not for the compiler.

Comment: Are You `using namespace XYZ;` in a global context?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk, im using it exactly as shown above, no other context except a trailing void main() { aaa::f(); }

Comment: Ad. Edit2) please describe the situation which You are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A) is there any way to prevent all objects in a namespace to be blind to its fellow constituents, and to require access always through :: ?

There isn't.

> B) if not, what would be the correct coding practice to obtain the desired behavior?

Use a `class`.

> C) if not, an alternative solution would be to separate the aaa namespace into 2, one for functions and another for variables, like f_aaa and v_aaa. but this seems quite clunky and ugly in practical use, eg. void f_sqlite::myfun() { v_sqlite::myvar; } instead of just void sqlite::myfun() { sqlite::myvar; }

Use a `class` to group relevant functions and data together. What You want to hide put in a `private` section.

Answer (score -1):

Using a separate (nested) namespace for function and variable is not a good idea.  It make the code less readable.

Also always qualifying all names is overkill. If the function `f` is in namespace `aaa` then it should really prefer variables from that namespace.

And finally the only reason why you would have such problem is because you are using too much global variables (or long functions) which is really a bad practice because it make the code harder to maintain.

So **I recommend you to use to use good coding practices** like

- small functions (less than a screen)
- avoid global variables
- object-oriented design using class with member functions and data when appropriate.
- small files (so you don't get irrelevant stuff)
- avoid variables in header files
- include only the files you really need (thus you won't get many conflicts if any)

In fact, if you really have the issue you have, **it is because current code is large and don't follow good practices..**

Other workarounds in comments and answers might works but better to validate if your design is adequate and refactor your code as appropriate.

**Extra points:**

Another thing that might cause lot of ambiguities is to use basic data type when you should really use custom types.

- Uses typed enumeration (`enum class`) when you want to use some constant for specific parameter instead of `define` or integers.
- Uses class or struct if you have data that are bundled together and are used all over the application.
- If you use template functions, you might want to carefully consider what kind of data it would allows particularly if you have a common name like `open` for the function.

Comment: thx f. ur advice. could u elab. a little wrt how to go about using classes for bundling. in our code there are many "bundles", one f. sqlite stuff, one f. algorithms, one f. comm. thru a specific api, etc. each bundle typically = ~20 smallish funcs + a larger #of vars that define constants & data structures. inside a bundle, the elements are semantically related but many "outside" functions will (also) use (eg.) a specific structure ins. the bundle. a consistent naming practice via namespaces was hoped to force-provide clarity. but the ability to access w.out qualifiers breaks that.